# join pivot table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How to join different tables with pivote table

I have 4 tables like

```
 users

 id  |  name |
 -------------
  1  |  abc  |
  2  |  ccc  |

user_profile

id   |  user_id | email |
-------------------------------
1    |    1     | abc@gmail.com 
2    |    2     | ccc@gmail.com

skills

id    |  skill_name  |
--------------------------
1    |   java       |
2    |   php        | 

user_skills

user_id   | skill_id   |
---------------------------
 1       |   1        |
 1       |   2        |
 2       |   1        |
```

The result should be

```
 name  |  email       |  skills   |
 ----------------------------------
 abc   |abc@gmail.com | java, php |
 ccc   |ccc@gmail.com | java      |
```

I am able to join multiple tables but I have problem joining pivote

I have tried below with query

```
 SELECT users.name,user_profiles.email, group_concat(programs.name) 
 from users
 JOIN user_profiles on user_profiles.user_id = users.id
 LEFT JOIN user_skills on user_skills.user_id = users.id
 LEFT JOIN skills on user_skills.skill_id = skills.id
 GROUP BY users.id
```

Can anyone help me on this please??Thanks

Comment: Make your group concat on `skills.skill_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `GROUP_CONCAT` to generate the CSV list of skills:

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    up.email,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.skill_name) AS skills
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_profile up
    ON u.id = up.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_skills us
    ON u.id = us.user_id
INNER JOIN skills s
    ON us.skill_id = s.id
GROUP BY
    u.id, u.name, up.email;
```

### Demo

Note that I group by both the user's id and name, because perhaps two users happen to have the same name.  Follow the link below for a running SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work.  Perhaps the problem is the reference to `programs` rather than `skills`:

```
select u.name, up.email, group_concat(s.name) 
from users u join
     user_profiles up
     on up.user_id = u.id left join
     user_skills us
     on us.user_id = u.id left join
     skills s
     on us.skill_id = s.id
group by u.name, up.email;
```